# Symfony routing: _controller special param

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

What is the use cases of `_controller` special param in Symfony routing system ?

The [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#special-routing-parameters) says:

> As you've seen, this parameter is used to determine which controller is executed when the route is matched.

But I already have `controller` configuration key to determine which controller to execute:

```
homepage:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::homepageAction
```

Using `_controller` param the very same result can be achived this way:

```
homepage:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::homepageAction
```

So, this is it ? Or does it has some other scenarios it can be used for ?

Comment: The defaults:_controller was the original way to specify the controller action.  Not too long ago the configuration was refined to allow using just 'controller'.  They are absolutely equivalent.  The defaults section allows you to add additional parameters to your routes accessible via $route->attributes->get('whatever');

Comment: Thanks, this ambiguity is really confusing for me